# Prolog - Need information on facts

Tags: prolog, fact

Say I had a fact such as:

```
bigger(cat,mouse).
```

If I wanted to describe this to someone, would I be correct in saying "cat is the first term within this fact and mouse is the second term" or would I refer to the cat and mouse as atoms and say "the cat is the first atom within the fact and the mouse is the second".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first description is fair, being 'term' a recursive data structure: i.e. a term is either an atom, a number, or a struct, where a struct is 'name(arg1,arg2,...)', and each argument is a term.

So your second description it's more accurate (restricted).

As other answers noted, 'argument' it's the usual naming of positionally identified attributes in structured terms.

Answer (score 0):

argument would be the perfect word I think. But usually to describe a predicate you'd use the following form :

```
predicate/arity : predicate(arguments...)
description of arguments
```

Here it'd go something like :

```
bigger/2 : bigger(Bigger, Lesser)
Holds if Bigger is bigger than Lesser.
```

Additionally you could precise the mode of the arguments : + for input, - for output, ? for both (and @ for a pure input), refer to @false's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283091/what-does-mode-in-prolog-mean/8284733#8284733) to get more infos about modes if needed.

Here the complete version could be :

```
bigger/2 : bigger(?Bigger, ?Lesser)
Holds if Bigger is bigger than Lesser.
```

Answer (score 0):

To mix things up a bit, I might say `bigger` is a binary relationship that holds between `cat` and `mouse`.