# What is the meaning of the double plus (++) instantiation mode in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Tags: prolog, signature, eclipse-clp

A comprehensive list of Prolog instantiation modes is given in a previous question: [*Meaning of instantiation mode indicators in arguments of Prolog predicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268558/meaning-of-instantiation-mode-indicators-in-arguments-of-prolog-predicates).

However, I have not been able to find any reference to or explanation about the double plus (++) instantiation mode in ECLiPSe Prolog. An example predicate in the ECLiPSe docs that uses the '++' mode is [setval(++,?)](http://eclipseclp.org/doc_5_9/bips/kernel/arrays/setval-2.html).

Does anyone know what the meaning is of this mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mode is described in http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/compiler/mode-1.html as having the following meaning: **++  The argument is ground.**

Comment: Thanks! I should've been able to find that, but for the life of me I couldn't.