# SWI: '+', '-', '--', '?' marks

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Are there any examples of how argument mode indicators work?

There's something about them in [SWI documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc).

But I have no idea how they can be applied.

Comment: I see you already found the relevant documentation for SWI. AFAIK SWI does not have a hay to enforce mode indicators so you would use them for documentation and to keep the code readable

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268558/meaning-of-instantiation-mode-indicators-in-arguments-of-prolog-predicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [mode indicators](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc) and are used to indicate the mode each argument should be used when calling a goal and upon successful completion of the goal.

They may be enforced on runtime (for example using a `mode` directive) or just used as a hint of for documentation purposes (for example in the documentation of SWI).

The exact meaning of those indicators also depend on your prolog processor.
For example in SWI:

- `+` means that the argument should not be a free variable when calling the goal
- `--` means that the argument should be a free variable when calling the goal and would be instantiated there

To use them for documentation purposes and to keep the code readable you would use it like this (example taken from some old SWI implementation for `sum_list/2`):

```
%!  sum_list(+List, -Sum) is det.
%
%   Sum is the result of adding all numbers in List.
sum_list(Xs, Sum) :-
    sum_list(Xs, 0, Sum).

sum_list([], Sum, Sum).
sum_list([X|Xs], Sum0, Sum) :-
    Sum1 is Sum0 + X,
    sum_list(Xs, Sum1, Sum).
```

Comment: That's quite clear. But could you give an example of using those indicators?

Comment: I put a simple example. If you download the SWI sources you can check it all.