# Counter-intuitive behavior of min_member/2

Tags: prolog, min, clpfd

[**min_member**(*-Min, +List*)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=min_member/2)

True when Min is the smallest member in the standard order of terms. Fails if List is empty.

```
?- min_member(3, [1,2,X]).
X = 3.
```

The explanation is of course that variables come before all other terms in the standard order of terms, and unification is used. However, the reported solution feels somehow wrong.

How can it be justified? How should I interpret this solution?

EDIT:

One way to prevent `min_member/2` from succeeding with this solution is to change the standard library (SWI-Prolog) [implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#min_member/2) as follows:

```
xmin_member(Min, [H|T]) :-
    xmin_member_(T, H, Min).

xmin_member_([], Min0, Min) :-
    (   var(Min0), nonvar(Min)
    ->  fail
    ;   Min = Min0
    ).
xmin_member_([H|T], Min0, Min) :-
    (   H @>= Min0 
    ->  xmin_member_(T, Min0, Min)
    ;   xmin_member_(T, H, Min)
    ).
```

The rationale behind failing instead of throwing an instantiation error (what @mat suggests in his answer, if I understood correctly) is that this is a clear question:

"Is 3 the minimum member of `[1,2,X]`, when X is a free variable?"

and the answer to this is (to me at least) a clear "No", rather than "I can't really tell."

This is the same class of behavior as `sort/2`:

```
?- sort([A,B,C], [3,1,2]).
A = 3,
B = 1,
C = 2.
```

And the same tricks apply:

```
?- min_member(3, [1,2,A,B]).
A = 3.

?- var(B), min_member(3, [1,2,A,B]).
B = 3.
```

Comment: your beef is basically whether to treat these kind of predicates as higher level, or lower level tools. And they clearly are low level tools: *"True when Min is the smallest member in the standard order of terms"* - pretty clear (though maybe could be improved, saying "Min unifies with ...").

Comment: @WillNess Yes, this is a good way to put it in two sentences. "Unifies" is more descriptive than "is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common property of many (all?) predicates that depend on the standard order of terms, while the order between two terms can change after unification.  Baseline is the conjunction below, which cannot be reverted either:

```
?- X @< 2, X = 3.
X = 3.
```

Most predicates using a `-Value` annotation for an argument say that `pred(Value)` is the same
as `pred(Var), Value = Var`.  Here is another example:

```
?- sort([2,X], [3,2]).
X = 3.
```

These predicates only represent clean relations if the input is *ground*.  It is too much to demand the input to be ground though because they can be meaningfully used with variables, as long as the user is aware that s/he should not further instantiate any of the ordered terms.  In that sense, I disagree with @mat.  I do agree that constraints can surely make some of these relations sound.

Comment: Yes. About `sort/2`, the documentation says, "True if Sorted can be unified with a list holding the elements of List, sorted to the standard order of terms", and the behavior you show follows. With `min_member/2` it is a bit more cryptic.

Answer (score 7):

The actual source of confusion is [a common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710541/772868) with general Prolog code.  There is no clean, generally accepted classification of the kind of purity or impurity of a Prolog predicate. In a manual, and similarly in the standard, pure and impure built-ins are happily mixed together. For this reason, things are often confused, and talking about what should be the case and what not, often leads to unfruitful discussions.

> How can it be justified? How should I interpret this solution?

First, look at the "mode declaration" or "mode indicator":

**min_member(-Min, +List)**

In the SWI documentation, this describes the way how a programmer shall use this predicate. Thus, the first argument should be uninstantiated (and probably also unaliased within the goal), the second argument should be instantiated to a list of some sort.  For all other uses you are on your own. The system assumes that you are able to check that for yourself. Are you really able to do so? I, for my part, have quite some difficulties with this. ISO has a [different system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386816/772868%5D) which also [originates in DEC10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294290/772868).

Further, the implementation tries to be "reasonable" for unspecified cases. In particular, it tries to be steadfast in the first argument. So the minimum is first computed independently of the value of `Min`. Then, the resulting value is unified with `Min`. This robustness against misuses comes often at a price. In this case, `min_member/2` always has to visit the entire list. No matter if this is useful or not. Consider

```
?- length(L, 1000000), maplist(=(1),L), min_member(2, L).
```

Clearly, 2 is not the minimum of `L`. This could be detected by considering the first element of the list only. Due to the generality of the definition, the entire list has to be visited.

This way of handling output unification is similarly handled in the standard.  You can spot those cases when the (otherwise) declarative description ([which is the first of a built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312956/772868)) explicitly refers to unification, like

> #### 8.5.4 copy_term/2
>
> #### 8.5.4.1 Description
>
> `copy_term(Term_1, Term_2)` is true iff `Term_2` unifies
> with a term `T` which is a renamed copy (7.1.6.2) of
> `Term_1`.

or

> #### 8.4.3 sort/2
>
> #### 8.4.3.1 Description
>
> `sort(List, Sorted)` is true iff `Sorted` unifies with
> the sorted list of `List` (7.1.6.5).

Here are those arguments (in brackets) of built-ins that can only be understood as being output arguments. Note that there are many more which effectively are output arguments, but that do not need the process of unification *after* some operation. Think of 8.5.2 `arg/3` (3) or 8.2.1 `(=)/2` (2) or (1).

8.5.4 1 `copy_term/2` (2),
[8.4.2 `compare/3` (1)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#compare),
[8.4.3 `sort/2` (2)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#sort),
[8.4.4 `keysort/2` (2)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#keysort),
8.10.1 `findall/3` (3),
8.10.2 `bagof/3` (3),
8.10.3 `setof/3` (3).

So much for your direct questions, there are some more fundamental problems behind:

### Term order

Historically, "standard" term order<sup>1</sup> has been defined to permit the definition of `setof/3` and `sort/2` about 1982. (Prior to it, as in 1978, it was not mentioned in the DEC10 <s>manual</s> user's guide.)

From 1982 on, term order was frequently (erm, ab-) used to implement other orders, particularly, because DEC10 did not offer higher-order predicates directly. `call/N` was to be invented two years later (1984) ; but needed some more decades to be generally accepted. It is for this reason that Prolog programmers have a somewhat nonchalant attitude towards sorting. Often they *intend* to sort terms of a certain kind, but prefer to use `sort/2` for this purpose — without any additional error checking. A further reason for this was the excellent performance of `sort/2` beating various "efficient" libraries in other programming languages decades later (I believe STL had a bug to this end, too). Also the complete magic in the code - I remember one variable was named `Omniumgatherum` - did not invite copying and modifying the code.

Term order has two problems: variables (which can be further instantiated to invalidate the current ordering) and infinite terms. Both are handled in current implementations without producing an error, but with still undefined results. Yet, programmers assume that everything will work out. Ideally, there would be comparison predicates that produce
instantiation errors for unclear cases [like this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26720685/772868). And another error for incomparable infinite terms.

Both [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dlists.html#index-min_005fmember_002f_005b2_002c3_005d-_0028lists_0029-2901) and SWI have `min_member/2`, but only SICStus has `min_member/3` with an additional argument to specify the order employed. So the goal

```
?- min_member(=<, M, Ms).
```

behaves more to your expectations, but only for numbers (plus arithmetic expressions).

---

Footnotes:

1 I quote standard, in standard term order, for this notion existed since about 1982 whereas the standard was published 1995.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly `min_member/2` is not a true relation:

```
?- min_member(X, [X,0]), X = 1.
X = 1.
```

yet, after simply exchanging the two goals by (highly desirable) commutativity of conjunction, we get:

```
?- X = 1, min_member(X, [X,0]).
false.
```

This is clearly quite bad, as you correctly observe.

*Constraints* are a declarative solution for such problems. In the case of integers, finite domain constraints are a completely declarative solution for such problems.

Without constraints, it is best to throw an *instantiation error* when we know too little to give a sound answer.

Comment: I was trying to find a behavior that best fits the _question_ asked by a query and _answer_ we get by looking at the solution. So, asking, "Is 3 the minimum member of [1,2,X]", I would expect the answer "No" rather than an instantiation error.

Comment: Yes, in this case, clearly enough is known to give a definite answer, so it does not fall in the category "we know too little to give a sound answer". In your example code, also think about cases when the length of the list is not yet known! `?- min_member(X, Xs).` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `min_member/2` is implemented:

```
min_member(Min, [H|T]) :-
    min_member_(T, H, Min).

min_member_([], Min, Min).
min_member_([H|T], Min0, Min) :-
    (   H @>= Min0
    ->  min_member_(T, Min0, Min)
    ;   min_member_(T, H, Min)
    ).
```

So it seems that `min_member/2` actually tries to **unify** `Min` (the first argument) with the smallest element in `List` in the standard order of terms.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not off-topic with this third answer. I did not edit one of the previous two as I think it's a totally different idea. I was wondering if this undesired behaviour:

```
?- min_member(X, [A, B]), A = 3, B = 2.
X = A, A = 3,
B = 2.
```

can be avoided if some conditions can be postponed for the moment when `A` and `B` get instantiated.

```
promise_relation(Rel_2, X, Y):-
    call(Rel_2, X, Y),
    when(ground(X), call(Rel_2, X, Y)),
    when(ground(Y), call(Rel_2, X, Y)).

min_member_1(Min, Lst):-
    member(Min, Lst),
    maplist(promise_relation(@=<, Min), Lst).
```

What I want from `min_member_1(?Min, ?Lst)` is to expresses a relation that says `Min` will always be lower (in the standard order of terms) than any of the elements in `Lst`.

```
?- min_member_1(X, L), L = [_,2,3,4], X = 1.
X = 1,
L = [1, 2, 3, 4] .
```

If variables get instantiated at a later time, the order in which they get bound becomes important as a comparison between a free variable and an instantiated one might be made.

```
?- min_member_1(X, [A,B,C]), B is 3, C is 4, A is 1.
X = A, A = 1,
B = 3,
C = 4 ;
false.
?- min_member_1(X, [A,B,C]), A is 1, B is 3, C is 4.
false.
```

But this can be avoided by unifying all of them in the same goal:

```
?- min_member_1(X, [A,B,C]), [A, B, C] = [1, 3, 4].
X = A, A = 1,
B = 3,
C = 4 ;
false.
```

**Versions**

If the comparisons are intended only for instantiated variables, `promise_relation/3` can be changed to check the relation only when both variables get instantiated:

```
promise_relation(Rel_2, X, Y):-
    when((ground(X), ground(Y)), call(Rel_2, X, Y)).
```

A simple test:

```
?- L = [_, _, _, _], min_member_1(X, L), L = [3,4,1,2].
L = [3, 4, 1, 2],
X = 1 ;
false.
```

**!** Edits were made to improve the initial post thanks to false's comments and suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I've changed `Goal =.. [Rel, X, Y], Goal` to `call(Rel, X, Y)`. Bad old habits.

Comment: One minor issue: Use instead of `Rel` rather `Rel_2` in this manner it is evident that the term expects two further arguments. Nobody uses _2 variables for anything, so this is clear.

Comment: What you consider is to make a predicate safe by delaying its execution. This has been extensively experimented in the 1980s particularly with MU and NU-Prolog to no big avail. It seems that you frequently end up with much too many "floundering" goals than you can manage. And it then starts to become really hard.  In case you want more: simply ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I have an observation regarding your `xmin_member` implementation. It fails on this query:

```
?- xmin_member(1, [X, 2, 3]).
false.
```

I tried to include the case when the list might include free variables. So, I came up with this:

```
ymin_member(Min, Lst):-
    member(Min, Lst),
    maplist(@=<(Min), Lst).
```

Of course it's worse in terms of efficiency, but it works on that case:

```
?- ymin_member(1, [X, 2, 3]).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- ymin_member(X, [X, 2, 3]).
true ;
X = 2 ;
false.
```

Comment: Yes, I meant it to fail though. According to standard order of terms, a free variable is "smaller" than any nonvar, and obviously, X is not 1 (it can be _unified_ with 1, however...). I would be happy if the documentation is just a bit more clear on this. See also @Jan's answer.

Comment: I know that for SWI-Prolog it was just a problem with the documentation for that predicate. But I thought the challenge was to implement an as general as it's possible version of `min_member/2`.

Comment: I guess my underlying question was rather, "how should I react when I see such behavior," and later, "when should I expect it from library predicates." This is a useful answer nevertheless.