# Prolog: How to eliminate duplicates of list of elements without changing the order of the elements?

Tags: duplicates, prolog

Being a beginner to prolog, I am trying to remove all duplicates from a list.
I do get a satisfying answer but this should be the only answer. Instead,
prolog keeps on providing other answers.

I try to make the code below working with the **example query** compress([a,a,b,c],S).
The only answer should be S = [a, b, c],
instead of getting an infinite amount of solutions with free variables:

```
S = [a, b, c|_1422]
S = [a, b, _1420, c|_1428]
S = [a, b, _1420, _1426, c|_1434]
S = [a, b, _1420, _1426, _1432, c|_1440].
```

I tried cuts, as illustrated in the code below. It is not a homework problem, I just really try to get it. Especially, I would like to know how I can get this specific code working instead of looking up someone elses code (I am aware that there should be way more sparse solutions). Thank you in advance!!!

```
compress([],[]).
compress([],_):-!. 
% I tried out a first cut here, but it doesn´t affect the amount of solutions
   
compress([Head|Tail],Set):-
    unique2(Head,Tail,Set),
    compress(Tail,Set).

unique2(X,[],[_List]):-!.  
% I tried out a second cut here, but again there is an endless amount of answers
unique2(X,List,List):-
     member(X,List).
unique2(X,List,List2):-
     member(X,List2).
unique2(X,List,NewList):-
    not(member(X,NewList)),
    addelem(X,List,NewList).

addelem(X,List,[X|List]).
```

Comment: Can you explain what `unique2` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: unique2 should detect if an element from List is already present in NewList (i.e. third argument of unique2). If it is not, it should be added to the new List. If it is already, it should not (as in unique2(X,List,List2):-
    member(X,List2).) where List2 stays the same. 

The second clause of unique2 is used after calling unique2(Head,Tail,Set) from within compress and I see now that there is a huge problem with it: the head only is not immediately repeated. When the same element occurs later or when another element occurs twice or more (e.g. compress([a,a,b,b,c],S).) the duplicates stay.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to note:**
From your comment:

> unique2 should detect if an element from List is already present in NewList (i.e. third argument of unique2). If it is not, it should be added to the new List. If it is already, it should not (as in unique2(X,List,List2):- member(X,List2).) where List2 stays the same. The second clause of unique2 is used after calling unique2(Head,Tail,Set) from within compress and I see now that there is a huge problem with it: the head only is not immediately repeated. When the same element occurs later or when another element occurs twice or more (e.g. compress([a,a,b,b,c],S).) the duplicates stay.

I think that you're overthinking youro `unique2` predicate.

Your `unique2` just need do something like this:

```
try_add( H , T ,    S  , S  ) :- member(H,T), !.
try_add( H , _ , [H|S] , S  ) .
```

And your `compress/2` needs to handle the terminating case (the empty list). Once you do that, you've got this: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/sypssqLO.pl

```
compress( []          , []  ) .
compress( [Head|Tail] , Set ):-
    try_add(Head,Tail,Set, NextSet),
    compress(Tail,NextSet)
    .

try_add( H , T ,    S  , S  ) :- member(H,T), !.
try_add( H , _ , [H|S] , S  ) .
```

[and now, back to the original answer]

This will discard all but the last of any duplicates:

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/MghqGThB.pl

```
dedupe( []    ,    []  ) .
dedupe( [H|T] ,    Xs  ) :- member(H,T), !, dedupe(T,Xs).
dedupe( [H|T] , [H|Xs] ) :-                 dedupe(T,Xs).
```

To keep the first isn't much more complicated. We'll just use a helper predicate with an accumulator. Since it builds the result set in reverse order, we need to reverse it. That gives us this:

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/PHQgypMu.pl

```
dedupe( Xs, Ys ) :- dedupe(Xs,[],Rs) , reverse(Rs,Ys).

dedupe( []    , Ys , Ys ) .
dedupe( [H|T] , Ts , Ys ) :- member(H,Ts), !, dedupe(T,Ts,Ys).
dedupe( [H|T] , Ts , Ys ) :-                  dedupe(T,[H|Ts],Ys).
```

Comment: Thank you. All three versions now work for me and the dedupe versions are more simple to understand than my own. I also notice that indeed the order of elements is kept intact in the new set, in the second dedupe example because there the current head is checked against the new set Ts (instead of being checked against the original tail as in the first dedupe version). Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, `dedupe` is much faster if `memberchk` is used instead of `member`.

Comment: Prolog is not Scheme. it's got tail recursion modulo cons! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method without needing `reverse` which seems a little faster than `dedupe` (both using `memberchk` for performance, which is optimized in swi-prolog):

```
remove_duplicate_elems([], []).
remove_duplicate_elems([H|T], [H|Uniqs]) :-
    % Seed Seen with H
    remove_duplicate_elems_(T, [H], Uniqs).

remove_duplicate_elems_([], _, []).
remove_duplicate_elems_([H|T], Seen, Uniqs) :-
    memberchk(H, Seen), !,
    remove_duplicate_elems_(T, Seen, Uniqs).
remove_duplicate_elems_([H|T], Seen, [H|Uniqs]) :-
    remove_duplicate_elems_(T, [H|Seen], Uniqs).
```

Performance comparison in swi-prolog:

```
?- numlist(1, 10_000, NL1), numlist(1, 10_000, NL2),
numlist(1, 10_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L),
time(remove_duplicate_elems(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).
% 89,999 inferences, 2.324 CPU in 2.327 seconds (100% CPU, 38726 Lips)

?- numlist(1, 10_000, NL1), numlist(1, 10_000, NL2),
numlist(1, 10_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L),
time(dedupe(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).
% 100,004 inferences, 2.414 CPU in 2.417 seconds (100% CPU, 41424 Lips)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
remove_duplicate_elems([], []).
remove_duplicate_elems([H|T], [H|Clean]) :-
    remove_elem_all(T, H, Clean1),
    remove_duplicate_elems(Clean1, Clean).

remove_elem_all([], _, []).
remove_elem_all([H|T], E, L) :-
    % Discard duplicate
    (   H == E -> L = L0
    ;   L = [H|L0]
    ),
    remove_elem_all(T, E, L0).
```

... but it is slower than `dedupe`:

```
?- numlist(1, 3_000, NL1), numlist(1, 3_000, NL2),
numlist(1, 3_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L),
time(remove_duplicate_elems(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).
% 13,507,501 inferences, 1.531 CPU in 1.513 seconds (101% CPU, 8823982 Lips)

?- numlist(1, 3_000, NL1), numlist(1, 3_000, NL2),
numlist(1, 3_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L),
time(dedupe(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).
% 13,522,504 inferences, 1.260 CPU in 1.245 seconds (101% CPU, 10730775 Lips)
```

Using `memberchk` instead of `member` in `dedupe`, **doubles the performance** in swi-prolog:

```
?- numlist(1, 3_000, NL1), numlist(1, 3_000, NL2),
numlist(1, 3_000, NL3), append([NL1, NL2, NL3], L),
time(dedupe(L, LU)), length(LU, LULen).
% 30,004 inferences, 0.682 CPU in 0.674 seconds (101% CPU, 43994 Lips)
```

Answer (score -1):

A fun way to achieve this is with

```
nub(L,R):- maplist( flip(memberchk,R), L), length(R,_), !.

flip(P,A,B) :- G =.. [P,B,A], G.
```