# Remove duplicates in a list without using built-in predicates and maintaining order

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and want to remove duplicates and maintain order. My logic is taking a list, dividing it to a Head|Tail, taking an accumulator and solving recursively as:
is head in accumulator?
yes- do nothing
no - add head to accumulator

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
is_member(X,[X|_]).
is_member(X,[_|T]) :- is_member(X,T).

remove_duplicates(List, Set) :- help_remove_duplicate(List, [], Set).


help_remove_duplicate([], Acc, Acc). 


help_remove_duplicate([H|T], Acc, Set) :- 
   is_member(H, A),
   help_remove_duplicate(T, Acc, Set).

help_remove_duplicate([H|T], Acc, Set) :- 
   help_remove_duplicate(T, [H|Acc], Set).
```

The above code works for removing duplicates but messes up the order.

[1,2,3,4,4,4,5] returns [5,4,3,2,1].

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74024975/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog: How to eliminate duplicates of list of elements without changing the order of the elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720605/prolog-how-to-eliminate-duplicates-of-list-of-elements-without-changing-the-ord)