# Removing duplicates from a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement a simple predicate, that would simply remove items that occur more than once in a list.
For instace, for,

```
unique([a,b,a,b,c,c,a], R)
```

should be `R = [a,b,c]`

```
unique([], []).
unique([X], [X]).

unique([H|T], [H|R]) :-
    not_contains(H, R),
    unique(T, R).
    
unique([H|T], R) :-
    contains(H, R),
    unique(T, R).
    
contains(_, []).
contains(X, [X|T]).

not_contains(_, []).
not_contains(X, [H|T]) :-
    X \= H,
    not_contains(X, T).
```

I am unsure what I'm doing wrong. If the item is not contained within `R`, add to it and repeat, and if is, don't add it and proceed with iteration.

Comment: "*I am unsure what I'm doing wrong.*" - You built code which depends on `contains` without testing whether `contains` works. Try `?- contains(3, [1,2,3,4,5]).`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720605/prolog-how-to-eliminate-duplicates-of-list-of-elements-without-changing-the-ord

Comment: develop small utilities, so small that it is easy for you to test and combine them effortlessly. test each separately and be sure that it's working as you intended, first. it's known as incremental, REPL-based development. IOW, your current question is not focused enough. it has not enough details - specifically, the test call and results/errors it produces.

Answer (score 1):

A fun way to do it that I just thought of:

```
nub(L,R):- maplist( p(R), L), length(R,_), !.

p(R,E):- memberchk(E,R).
```

`nub(L,R)` makes a unique list `R` out of an input list `L`. It assumes `R` is a non-instantiated variable before the call is made, and `L` is a fully ground list.

This uses the result list as its own uniqueness accumulator while it is being built!

Testing:

```
6 ?- nub([a,b,a,b,c,c,a], R).
R = [a, b, c].
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a list unique is just use the built-in `sort/2`:

```
unique(Xs,Ys) :- sort(Xs,Ys).
```

so `unique( [c,a,b,a] , Rs )` yields `Rs = [a,b,c]`.

If you want to maintain order, you need to decide on the strategy you want to use — in case of duplicates, which duplicate "wins": First or last?

The "last wins" strategy is the simplest to implement:

```
unique( []     , [] ) .  % the empty list is itself a unique set
unique( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :- % A non-empty list is unique if . . .
  contains(X,Xs),        % - X is contained within the source list's tail,
  !,                       - and (eliminating the choice point)
  unique( Xs,   Ys  ) .    - omitting X, the remainder of the list is (recursively) unique
unique( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :- % Otherwise, the non-empty list is unique if . . .
  unique( Xs,[X|Ys] ) .  % - adding X to the results, the remainder of the list is (recursively) unique .
```

Here, `unique( [a,b,a,c,a], Rs )` yields `Rs = [b,c,a]`.

If you want to use the "first wins" strategy, you'll be wanting to use a *helper predicate* with an accumulator that grows the result list in reverse order, which is then reversed. That gives us something like this:

```
unique( Xs , Ys ) :- unique(Xs,[],Zs), reverse(Zs,Ys) .

unique( []     , Ys , Ys ) .  % Source list exhausted? we're done.
unique( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- % Otherwise . . .
  contains(X,Ts) ,            % - if X is found in the accumulator,
  !,                          % - eliminate the choice point, and
  unique(Xs,Ts,Ys) .          % - recurse down, discarding X
unique( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- % Otherwise (X is unique) . . .
  unique(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys) .      % - recurse down, prepending X to the accumulator
```

And here, `unique( [a,b,a,c,a], Rs )` yields `Rs  = [a,b,c]`.

You can avoid the use of `reverse/2` here, by building the 2 lists (accumulator and final set) in parallel. A trade-off, though: memory for speed:

```
unique( Xs , Ys ) :- unique(Xs,[],Ys) .

unique( []     , _  ,    []  ) .
unique( [X|Xs] , Ts ,    Ys  ) :- memberchk(X,Ts), !, unique( Xs, Ts     , Ys ) .
unique( [X|Xs] , Ts , [X|Ys] ) :-                     unique( Xs, [X|Ts] , Ys ) .
```

You don't really need a `contains/2` predicate: the in-built `member/2` and `memberchk/2` do exactly what you want. `member/2` is non-deterministic and will succeed once for every time the item is found in the list; `memberchk/2` is non-deterministic and will succeed at most once.

Since this is testing for uniqueness, `memberchk/2` is what you'd want, giving you this:

```
contains(X,Ys) :- memberchk(X,Ys) .
```

Or you can roll you own (it's trivial):

```
contains( X , [X|Ys] ) :- ! .
contains( X , [_|Ys] ) :- contains(X,Ys) .
```

Or even simpler, just a one-liner:

```
contains( X , [Y|Ys] ) :- X = Y -> true ; contains(X,Ys) .
```

Comment: you *really* don't need `reverse` here.

Comment: Updated to add an option that doesn't use reverse.

Comment: why it's "a trade-off: memory for speed"? your amended version builds exactly the same structures in memory, and it spares the reverse call so if anything _it_ (the new one) is more memory efficient, not less, AFAICS.